# Oracle. Select all if parameter is null else return specific item issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to return all records if input parameter is null.

I've written a simple query

```
declare  
   l_sql varchar2(100);
   i number := 1;
 begin
   l_sql:= 'EXPLAIN PLAN for select * from job where :i is null or id = :i';
   execute immediate l_sql;
   commit;
  end;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.display); 

| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |  1386 |   217K|   226   (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|   1 |  PARTITION LIST ALL|      |  1386 |   217K|   226   (1)| 00:00:03 |     1 |    13 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| JOB  |  1386 |   217K|   226   (1)| 00:00:03 |     1 |    13 |
```

As you can see index is not working, but if I remove ":i is null" check index starts to work.

```
declare  
   l_sql varchar2(100);
   i number := 1;
 begin
   l_sql:= 'EXPLAIN PLAN for select * from job where id = :i';
   execute immediate l_sql;
   commit;
  end;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.display);

| Id  | Operation                          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                                                                                                             

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |           |     1 |   161 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |                                                                                                                                                                                             
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| JOB       |     1 |   161 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |                                                                                                                                                                                             
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IX_JOB_ID |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
```

So what is the better way to complete this task? Why index is not work in that situation?

Keep in mind that procedure can have many such parameters.

Comment: The main question is how to make the index work?

Comment: I have posted an answer, and if you an index, my solution should work. Could you please also include the index metadata. And, please comment on my answer whether my solution works for you.

Comment: Even this query gives full table scan:
select *
from job j
where j.id = 1 or 1 = 1

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `coalesce`. It is the most readable and understandable way to write this. Since the logic is contained in one predicate, it's easier to maintain and remove:

```
select * from job where id = coalesce(:i, id)
```

---

As requested, a 'proof' this actually uses the index:

```
create table x ( id number(15) null );

create unique index x_pk on x( id );

select id
from   x
where  id = coalesce(:x, id)
; -- Uses index

select id
from   x
where  id = :x or :x is null
; -- Full table scan
```

Plan:

> SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS Cost: 1  Bytes: 13  Cardinality: 1
>
> 1 INDEX FULL SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) X_PK Cost: 1  Bytes: 13  Cardinality: 1

Comment: It didn't help.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Index still doesn't work.

2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL

2 - filter("ID"=COALESCE(:I,"ID"))

Comment: Usually `or` is the problem with indexes. This should work because the `coalesce` is handled before the equation. Are you sure the index has been built?

Comment: Patrick, if it is possible for you, my suggestion would be to post a test case. It will be a good case to discuss :-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Proving what?

Comment: That coalesce in the filter predicate uses the index. I wish I knew about it, but I need to test it. Since, OP says it isn't using the index, so I suggested you to post a test case. I will definitely try it and get back to you if the results are different from what you state. It would be a good thing to discuss.

Comment: `NOT NULL` constraint won't allow NULL values. Remove it, let the NULL values be there, and then test it. Let's see what happens then.

Answer (score 1):

`IS NULL` suppresses the `index` usage. Because `NULL` values are not indexed.

There are two ways to make the use of index with `IS NULL` :

1.`BITMAP` index. However, more applicable in `OLTP` systems.

2.My favourite way, and nice to demonstrate. We could make the **`leaves of the b-tree index a constant`**. Thus, making use of index while querying for `NULL`. Basically, the NULLs are all together, at the top/bottom of the index. Oracle can use the index `forwards or backwards`, so doesn't really matter. And it does a **`full scan of the index`**.

I have answered a similar question here http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/194746/625371/#msg_625371

**The first scenario won't use the index due to the OR is null condition :**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM PROD_NEW;

PROFILE_TYPE
---------------

Prod
Prodparallel

Prod

SQL> CREATE INDEX PROD_NEW_I1 ON PROD_NEW
  2    (PROFILE_TYPE
  3    );

Index created.

SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM PROD_NEW WHERE PROFILE_TYPE = 'Prod' OR PROFILE_TYPE IS NULL;

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2121244107

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |          |     3 |    15 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| PROD_NEW |     3 |    15 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("PROFILE_TYPE" IS NULL OR "PROFILE_TYPE"='Prod')

13 rows selected
```

**Let's make the leaves constant :**

```
SQL> DROP INDEX PROD_NEW_I1;

Index dropped.

SQL> CREATE INDEX PROD_NEW_I1 ON PROD_NEW
  2    (PROFILE_TYPE,1
  3    );

Index created.

SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM PROD_NEW WHERE PROFILE_TYPE = 'Prod' OR PROFILE_TYPE IS NULL;

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1272076902

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |             |     3 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | PROD_NEW_I1 |     3 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("PROFILE_TYPE" IS NULL OR "PROFILE_TYPE"='Prod')

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: ok Thank you.
But I need to check on null input parameter, not the table field.
What would you suggest in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me show the full story behind the Val's question.

We need to produce the report from the Job table which has following fields :

- Id not null,
- JobNumber not null,
- JobDate not null,
- MissedReasonId null,
- FollowUpReasonId null ....

The report filter form produces the input parameters for the report stored procedure.

Among other parameters there are two check list boxes on that filter form to check the required Missed Reason items or/and FolowUp Reason items.

As you can see MissedReasonId and FollowUpReasonId are nullable therefore if user doesn't check any item in those check list boxes we need to show all the jobs.

If some of the items are checked we send them to the stored procedure as a delimited ID list.

We are trying to get the data using one single query.

The assumption is :

- If Id list input parameter is empty I don't want Oracle to check if the value of (lets say) MissedReasonId is in the provided delimited list (MissedReasonIdList).
- If Id list is not empty lets select only those records which
  have MissedReasonId value in the provided list.

There's no problem with the ID list itself. We can convert it into table or an array and make selection working fast enough.
There's no problem if the ID list is mandatory on the filter form (we don't need to check the parameter for null).
The problem arises then it is not mandatory (parameter can be null) and there are multiple filter conditions like that on the filter form.

The query we are using looks like this :

```
Select j.Id , j.JobNumber  .....
  From Job j
  left join MissedReason mr on mr.ID = j.MissedReasonId 
  left join FollowUpReason fr on fr.ID = j.FollowUpReasonId
  ....
  Where
    (j.JobDate between P_StartDate and P_EndDate)
    and ( P_MissedReasonIdList is null or (j.MissedReasonId "IS IN THAT P_MissedReasonIdList"))
    and ( P_FollowUpReasonIdList is null or (j.FollowUpReasonId "IS IN THAT MissedReasonIdList"))
    and ......
```

We expected that if an input parameter is null in the first part of the WHERE condition :

"and ( P_MissedReasonIdList is null or (j.MissedReasonId "IS IN THAT P_MissedReasonIdList"))"

Oracle shouldn't bother to check the second part of the condition. **(This is what Val mentioned in his question. Right Val ?)**

I really don't want to build the dynamic query on the fly including only those conditions which should be checked into query.

But is there any other solution to our problem ?