# Oracle index with nested conditions

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, runtime

I have a query, something like 
select * from table1 where :iparam is null or iparam = field1;

On field1 there is a non-unique index, but oracle (11g) don't want to use it. As i understand, it optimize query not in run-time, but at compiling. I'm using such query in stored procedures. I wonder, if there is a way, to tell oracle, to use an indexes?

I know about "hints" but i would like to use something on all project, like some optimizer argument, to optimize queries in run-time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630354/stored-procedure-sql-execution-plan/29634329#29634329. (Asked the same day)

Answer (score 1):

> where :iparam is null or :iparam = field1;

Oracle has no way of knowing in advance if you will pass NULL value for :iparam 
If you do, full scan is the best way to access data. If you don't, index might be better. You can split this statement in two parts using IF, then there will be no ambiguity.

If you have a lot of fields to compare, dynamic sql migh be a better way.

```
IF :param1 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_sql := v_sql||' and field1 = :param1';
ELSE
  v_sql := v_sql||' and nvl(:param1,1) = 1';
END IF;
```

ELSE part is for easyer usage of USING.

Comment: My problem is, that i have a huge query, with ~30 such conditions... could you give me and example, for something like: 

select * from table 1 where (:param1 is null or :param1 = field1) and (:param2 is null or :param2 = field2) and (:param3 is null or :param3 = field3) and (:param4 is null or :param4 = field4)

My task is to optimize such query...

Comment: Edited answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that the execution plan is determined at the time of package compilation. It will be determined just before the query is actually executed.

How the optimizer decides to run the query depends on many things. Foremost the availability of statistics. These give the optimizer something to go on. How many records are in the table. How many different values are in the index.

Here is an article that goes into more detail:
http://joco.name/2014/01/05/why-wouldnt-oracle-use-a-perfectly-valid-index/